# How to send a request to server without using external lib in android

Tags: android, httprequest

I have a question about communication with android phone and web service. In last time, I used apache lib to communicate with server. However, in current task, I just want to send a request to server, and I do not care aboutany respond from server. Could we have any simple way (that does not use any external lib (i.e apache)) for my task? I am using Android studio and SDK 23.

Besides, Do we have any way to check that the my phone sent the request successfully to server?

This is last code that used apache

```
public static String getStringContent(String uri) throws Exception {
            try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(uri));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s;
            while(true )
            {
                s = buf.readLine();
                if(s==null || s.length()==0)
                    break;
                sb.append(s);    
            }
            buf.close();
            ips.close();
            return sb.toString();    
            } 
        finally {
                   // any cleanup code...
                }
}
```

Hence, my solution is

```
URL urlToRequest = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlToRequest = new URL("server_link");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
       // urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, nothing is happen. I think I was wrong something in second code

Comment: You should use GET request, and remove "urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);"

Comment: Thanks, How to use get request in my second code?I will check it tomorrow. If it works, I will let you knows

Comment: As I said, remove the line urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);, then replace urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); by urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

Answer (score 1):

try this code. it is without external lib [downlaod full code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ir237mgxd2qlj2l/JsonParserApp.zip?dl=0)

```
public static String getData(String uri) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen that is not? Please be specific.

Comment: I think @ExceptionLover's code is OK, you said "not work", pls post any logcat info, moreover, you should use the code inside an asynctask.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek: Actually, when I typing the link in the browser, the server will be sent something to another server, Hence, I would like to process that procedure in my phone as the browser. I do not need the feedback or result in my phone, but when I call that link, that link must be processed as I type in my browser. Thanks

Comment: @BNK: Logcat does not show anything. The meaning of "not work" that means the my phone does not process the above link as browser. Because when I typed that link in the browser, my phone will be show something. However, doing same thing as above code, nothing is happend

Comment: sorry for late reply because there is internet problem in my city.... this code is fully runing download code from this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/ir237mgxd2qlj2l/JsonParserApp.zip?dl=0